# Package thumbs conflict with other packages

Tags: thesis

I am working on my thesis and want to have chapter thumbs for the research papers attached after the main text (a thesis summary, consisting of chapters and a bibliography).

I would like to:

- Load and use the package 'thumbs' without warnings or errors
- Use huge roman numbers at each thumb, preferably by automation
- Align the roman numbers at the thumb's center
- Only display thumb on specific pages (e.g., for each attached paper, either on the \chapter*{} page or the page before, but only odd pages)

The errors I get in my document:

```
LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.    ‪bu2.aux, 86‬
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                              
l.86 \newlabel
             {pagesLTS.arabic.local}{{}{46}{}{page.46}{}}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

And this one:

```
Package undolabl Error: Label `pagesLTS.arabic.local' shall be overridden
```

I have made minimal working example to troubleshoot the errors, and this way I have only had warnings:

```
Package undolabl Warning: Label `pagesLTS.arabic' overridden on input line 165.
```

They seem to be related to all sections (part, chapters, etc.)

See image for the result. It's at an ok size, but I haven't figured out how to display the number as a roman number, and how to control the number. I have now hardcoded it like "I" or "II" which is fine. I am also struggling with centering the letters.

Also see last image for desired output, what I am trying to achieve.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}  

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}                           
\onehalfspacing                                 
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper,                                
%To be shrunk to 80% when printed
                twoside,                                        %Two-side mode, switches margins on 
                bindingoffset = 2mm,                        
                %Offset for binding side of page
                hmargin = 25mm,                             
                %Left and right margin
                vmargin = 25mm,                             
                %Top and bottom margin
                dvipdfm]
                {geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}                        
\usepackage{natbib}     
\usepackage{bibunits}

\renewcommand\bibname{References}
% Change name of Bibliography to References
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}}
% Bibliography as a section without numbering

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage{booktabs}       
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage{mathptmx}               
\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}     
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{\setstretch{1}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
 
% Each \part in TOC introduced by "Part x"
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname~\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother

% Remove "Chapter x" from each \chapter
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont\fontfamily{phv}
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

% New command for changing tocdepth mid-document (for attached papers)
\newcommand{\changelocaltocdepth}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}}%
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}%
}

\usepackage[colorlinks,     
            citecolor=black,    
            linkcolor=black,  
            urlcolor=black,                     
            ]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{\autoref{#1}}         

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily \thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\sffamily \leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}                            
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}      
}

\hyphenpenalty=10
\tolerance=1000

\title{
{\huge \textbf{Main title}}\\
    \text{Subtitle}
    \author{
    \textbf{First-name Last-name}\vspace{2cm}\\
        Thesis \\
        Uni name\vspace{2.5em}  \\
        }   
    \date{}
}

\usepackage[letterspace=-45]{microtype}
\usepackage[height={=0.33\paperheight}, width=2cm]{thumbs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\mbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter 
%\include{0-scientific_environment}
%\include{0-acknowledgements}
%\include{0-abstract}
%\include{0-listofpublications}

\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\onehalfspacing

\mainmatter
%
%% Main chapters (example under)
%

%\begin{bibunit}[ACM-Reference-Format]
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum

\section{More}
\lipsum


\chapter{Background}

\lipsum

%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
%\putbib[references.bib]
%\end{bibunit}    

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\changelocaltocdepth{3}
% Includes subsubsection in TOC

%
% Paper 1
%
\chapter*{\Large\selectfont{\textcolor{darkgray}{Paper I}} \\ Name of paper} \addthumb{}{\textls{{\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont \bfseries{I}}}}{white}{darkgray}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Paper I -- Name of paper}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
%\begin{bibunit}[ACM-Reference-Format]
%\input{papers/paperi/paper-master}
%\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
%\putbib[references]
%\end{bibunit}
%\includepdf[pages={1-}]{papers/paperii.pdf}

\lipsum

%\setcounter{chapter}{0}
%\setcounter{section}{0}
%\setcounter{table}{0}

% Paper 2 etc.
\chapter*{\Large\selectfont{\textcolor{darkgray}{Paper II}} \\ Name of paper} \addthumb{}{\textls{{\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont \bfseries{II}}}}{white}{darkgray}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Paper I -- Name of paper}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
% and so forth

\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output]

[image: Desired result]

Comment: According to the package documentation, thumbs knows only the options eventxtindent and oddtxtindent to manipulate the position of the text. \centering does not work, while \hfill does. Besides: if you would omit the option [display] and \chaptertitlename\ of \titleformat{chapter} (instead of your laborious code to remove the Chapter X) and redefine it before inserting the papers, your code will improve.

Comment: thank you, I've updated the code with hfill and removed unnecessary complex code for removing chapter numbering.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP gave up on the problem. See comment below answer.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner How is this a reason to close this? A working answer could be helpful for others.

Comment: @JasperHabicht My naive reasoning was that in 1.5 years there was no feedback if the answer solved the problem and there was also no comment or followup question from somebody else. But I thought this is why we need five votes to make sure it is not just my opinion. I did not have bad intentions, rather housekeeping.

Comment: No strong feelings about it. The +1 that the answer has was from me.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sure, it may be not very likely, but I always though that an answer may be kept open as long as it is formulated in an appropriate way (regardless of the existence or likelihood of an answer).

Comment: Not sure what else I can reply :).

Comment: I thought that's what the voting system was for.

Comment: Yes, let‘s vote! 

Answer (score 1):

I tidied up your code a bit, but I cannot get rid of the error messages, nor can I activate

```
 \renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{5em}%
    \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Paper~}%
```

before paper I, having added

```
\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}
```

at the beginning.

This is your chapter title at the beginning:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}%[display]
{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
{%\chaptertitlename\ 
\thechapter.}{1em}{\setstretch{1}}%
```

This is your chapter title for the papers:

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\sffamily\bfseries\Large}{\selectfont\textcolor{darkgray}{Paper\space\thechapter}}{0.25\baselineskip}{} %
```

This is the definition of your thumb:

```
\usepackage[height={0.33\paperheight},width={2cm},eventxtindent={-2mm}]{thumbs}
\newcommand\mythumb{\addthumb{}{\textls{{\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont \bfseries{\hfill\thechapter\hfill}}}}{white}{darkgray}}%
```

which you apply by:

```
\chapter{Name of Paper}\mythumb
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've given up on thumbs for now, planning to add them manually without the use of latex.